# Messenger bot stopped replying

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I've been developing a bot for Messenger and it has been working fine for quite a while and than it just stopped showing messages.

When I send a request to send a message, I receive a response:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1157989877575188
    [url] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages
)
```

But nothing appears in the user chat. The bot is not replying.

No warning messages, no warnings in developer console. The bot is approved and has been working fine for weeks. It's frustrating because I don't even know where to look for errors.

Comment: You checked your bot for incoming messages from Facebook?

Comment: Of course, they sent this strange kind of response, which does not contain an arror, however, it does not contain message_id either

Answer (score 0):

Check your PHP code responses from Facebook for errors.

You should also double check that your Page Access token hasn't expired and if so then reset it.

```
curl -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/subscribed_apps?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>”
```

Comment: I didn't know these tokens can expire. I thought they would work forever, should I update them? Will I be notified by some field in the facebook response that my token is expired? Because I haven't seen any warnings in the responses.

Comment: Double check the Messenger section of your Facebook page for any errors. You normally get a notification there.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after half a day it just randomly started responding, even though I didn't do anything. It's still very curious what might have happened